# Integer division

Tags: arduino-uno, c++

I want to divide two integers and get how often one of them fits into the other completely, so there will always be an integer as an output. In python you do this kind of operation with `//`.

Comment: So... just pure integer division (doing division without the rest behind the decimal point)? Thats just the division operator / with integers. For example 13/4 will get you 3 (because both operants are integers, so the part behind the decimal point is ignored). Is that what you mean?

Comment: cast both numerator and denominator to integers of appropriate type and use division: `(int)num/(int)den` produces an int result (2-byte signed in arduino).   you may want to use stdint.h (aka cstdint) types like int16_t which make the types clear regardless of compiler (int is 4-byte signed in some places)
 you may find that casting at math operations is useful in other scenarios too.  for example, sometimes you want to handle integer rollover (255+1 will roll to 0 if they are 1-byte unsigned).

Answer (score 4):

In C++, the integer division operator is `/`, and the floating point
division is also `/`. The compiler chooses according to the types of the
operands:

- if either or both operands are floating points numbers, you get a
  floating point division
- if both operands are of some integer type, you get an integer
  division.

Thus:

- `5.0/2.0`, `5.0/2`, `5/2.0` all have the same value, namely `2.5`
- `5/2` is `2`.